# Is there any difference between "(rope) sold in 100 meter coils" and "(rope) sold by 100 meter coils"?

Tags: difference, prepositions

Can't get what variant is better when talking about 100 meter rope coil being sold (without possibility of cutting).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the US, "by the yard|foot" isn't antiquated.  Rope or wire can be sold 'by the foot' or 'by the coil'. Or one can say 'The rope comes in coils', where "comes in" means "is available for purchase in...". If a measurement is involved, one would say 'It is sold *in* 100-foot coils.'

Answer (score 0):

'in 100m coils' is quite correct & more comfortable than 'by 100m coils', which just feels altogether wrong.

'by' is reminiscent of the possibly antiquated 'by the yard' or 'by the metre'.
I think it works best for that - it implies you purchase any number of yards & are charged the amount per yard times the number of yards.

Reduce it still further, you are selling it 'in coils', but by the above token 'by the coil'.

That would tell me that it can only be 'by' if followed by the definite article & a singular noun, & that 'in' works better for plurals - but it would need a true grammarian to state with authority.

'by coil' doesn't work, neither does 'by coils'. Equally 'in the coil' fails.

Comment: Which is antiquated, "by the" or the unit, yard?

Comment: both, I guess, but I meant 'by the'